# Is Azure storage supported in Azure Static Web App functions?

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-static-web-app

I'm working on an API for an Azure Static Web App. The web app is implemented in Angular (although that isn't important for this question), and the API is implemented in C# (NET 6). Deployment to Azure is via a GitHub action.

I can create an HTTP trigger API endpoint that works fine, like so:

```cs
public static class Tester
{
    [FunctionName("Tester")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "v1/tester")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I'm also able to access this directly via the SWA URL: `https://<sitename>.azurestaticapps.net/api/v1/tester`.

However, as soon as I add a reference to an Azure storage NuGet package to the project file (specifically Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs), **making no other changes to the code**, the API endpoint no longer works once deployed (although it will work locally).

On deploying the code with that package referenced in the .csproj, hitting the API endpoint gives a 503 status code with the response:

> Function host is not running.

I enabled Application Insights for this static web app, and a `CryptographicException` is being thrown on startup:

> An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information. For more information go to http://aka.ms/dataprotectionwarning Could not find any recognizable digits.

(The link in the message doesn't go anywhere useful).

I'm presuming this has something to do with the `AzureWebJobsStorage` setting, which cannot be set in an Azure Static Web App (for whatever reason).

Based on all of the above, it would seem that using Azure storage from within a static web app C# function is verboten. However, I can't find that stated explicitly online anywhere. Has anybody got this kind of thing to work?

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: Seems like we're not allowed to name settings with certain prefixes, including AzureWeb... more details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis-functions#constraints

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following nuget packages to make it working:

```
Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid
```

I decomposed my http functions to a separate project because SWA does not support the EventTriggers right now.